# What do you flag an answer as when it's posted as a question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, declined-flags

Ran into [a bizarre question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27835852/4099598) yesterday that was actually (apparently?) an answer. Since it is now deleted, here is a screenshot:

[image]

It didn't seem to me that any of the normal flag reasons applied, so I picked Other and mentioned that it was an answer masquerading as a question. This was declined with the explanation that I should use a standard close reason, but no mention of which.

So, which *should* I have used?

It certainly isn't spam or offensive. It's (presumably) not a duplicate in any meaningful sense; at least I hope there are very few other answers-as-questions lingering! It's not really "very low quality" in the usual sense, as I understand it.

Let's go into "it should be closed for another reason". It's not off-topic (for any of the sub-reasons). It might be "unclear what they're asking", in that they aren't actually asking anything, but that felt wrong at the time; this is, however, the most likely. Certainly it is neither too broad nor opinion-based.

So the only possibilities are custom reasons or unclear. Still seems weird to use "unclear", though I can't exactly articulate why beyond feeling like it doesn't even reach the bar necessary to have a question to be phrased unclearly.

Comment: "Not an answer" :-).

Comment: @Ben Yeah I wish, right? *anachronistically bemoans the removal of NARQ*

Comment: You are aware that there is a close reason `off-topic -> other` that lets you type a custom comment, right? You can always pick this when you feel the other reasons do not apply.

Comment: @l4mpi: Yes, that's … exactly what I *did*. The flag was declined, which is why I posted. That's also why the last paragraph starts by mentioning the two remaining possibilities, one of which is "custom reasons".

Comment: @NathanTuggy No, that's the toplevel `other` flag for _moderator attention_, not for closing. But I just looked at the flag dialog again on a site where I don't have the closing privilege, and it seems like there is no equivalent flag to the `other` _close reason_, although I could swear it was there when I started on SO... This of course means that the custom comment option is only available once you have closing privileges.

Comment: @l4mpi. Ah. Well, yes, that would be it. I did exhaustively list all the options I had, barring the breakdown of off-topic.

Comment: I'm not native English speaker, but I will write the title as : **What do you flag a *question* as when it's an *answer*?**

Comment: Could someone please post a screenshot as reference for those of us who do not have enough reputation to view deleted questions?

Comment: @Bolu I am a native English speaker, and I agree with you. I thought this was going to be an answer (in the SO sense), that ended with a question mark.

Comment: @Bolu That's correct too, but the original title is perfectly fine (and IMO more clear). The difference is the inclusion of "posted as": an answer *posted as* a question definitely means someone clicked Ask a Question and then typed in an answer; an answer that *is* a question is a little vague but probably means they clicked Answer and then typed in a question. So your rephrasing would mean the same thing but be less clear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Honestly, had I been the mod who handled your flag, I would probably not have declined it.

You found a problematic post, which you could not directly close yourself, and did your best to deal with it, which brought it to the attention of people who *could* handle it.  We could argue all day about whether your choice really was the *best* possible one, but IMO, it certainly wasn't a *bad* choice.

That said, moderators are just people, too, and can have differences in opinion, or even simply make mistakes.  For instance, it may be that your flag was declined because the mod who handled it felt that you should've used one of the standard flags like "too broad" or "very low quality" instead, which would've fed the post directly into the review queue without having to go through the mods.  (I do consider this a valid argument, and might've also left you a note suggesting it, even if I'd also marked your flag as helpful.)

It's also possible that the mod who handled your flag simply didn't realize that you didn't yet have enough rep to cast close votes yourself, and thought that you should've done that instead.  Or maybe they just clicked "decline" instead of "helpful" by mistake.  Who knows?  In the end, a single declined flag does not really make all that much difference, anyway.

---

Anyway, on the subject of "what was the *right* thing to do here?", I'd like to highlight [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835852/how-to-edit-confluence-page-title-mobile-view-mode#comment44110493_27835852) posted below the "question" by [Josh Caswell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603977/josh-caswell):

> Thanks for trying to share the solution you've found to a problem. Please follow the format, however. [You can post a question and then answer it yourself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking), but the solution should be below, not in the body of the question.

IMO, *that* was the really important part.  Whether or how the non-question was flagged or closed is, ultimately, of little consequence — it was going to get closed *somehow* anyway.  What was important is that someone took the time to tell the new user who posted how to ask a *proper* question (and how to provide your own answer — which, yes, SO does allow and encourage, as long as it's done properly).  Hopefully, the user saw the comment, and may eventually end up contributing many useful questions and answers to SO.  Or, even if not, at least we tried.

Comment: It wasn't a particularly good choice because had the OP picked a standard close flag, it would have pushed it to a review queue if it wasn't already there and thus likely accelerated its closure through other users *with* the ability to cast close votes, all without needing to involve a moderator.

Comment: I mean I would have closed the question too (I wasn't the one who processed this flag), but I can see why the flag was declined.

Comment: I think this is a good summary, and helps reframe it to something I didn't pay as much attention to here.

Answer (score 25):

If you run into a question that is not a question you can flag as "should be closed for another reason" / "unclear what you are asking".

If you can't find a *question* in a post that should be a question, then it is unclear what the OP is asking. There is a presumption that when someone submits a question to the site, they *should* be asking something. It would be nice to have a flag that says "this is not even a question" but "unclear" does the job well enough.

Comment: OK, can you please expand on why this should be the case? I mean, obviously that's the most likely possibility the mod was thinking of, but I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: I've edited. I'm not sure what more I can add to make the case.

Answer (score 11):

> It's not really "very low quality"...

Actually, it is a very low quality *question*.  As an answer, the post would probably be OK, but it was submitted as a question.  Since it does not actually ask a question, it may be considered a 0% quality question.  Flagging it as such would have been appropriate.

That said, I personally would have used "unclear what you are asking" because it is more to the point.  I mean, the question is low quality because it does not clearly ask anything.  So, why not use the close reason dedicated specifically to posts like this?

Answer (score 4):

Moderators are exception handlers, so flags should only be used for things that regular users can't deal with.

In this case regular users **can** deal with this situation by down-voting and closing the question. If you don't have 3,000 reputation points yet then *flag* for closure. This will add the question to the close review queue where users with more than 3,000 reputation will see it and actually vote to close.

Once it's closed it can be deleted - again by regular users (or by the automatic clean-up processes that run regularly).

So, in this case your flag was, quite properly, declined as a moderator doesn't have to get involved with this at all.

Comment: OK. What should I have flagged it *as*? That's the only part I'm asking about; the rest I already know and do follow.

Comment: @Nathan you should have picked an off topic flag - unclear what you are asking - would be best. This puts the question onto the close review queue where other regular users can act on it.

Answer (score -5):

Edit the question so that it contains only the question.  Copy-paste the "answer" part of the question to an answer, and Community-Wiki it.

Don't go inventing your own close reasons or flag reasons.  And ABSOLUTELY don't pick a close reason or flag reason that doesn't quite apply, such as "unclear what you're asking", because it's abundantly clear what is being asked.

Comment: At the time I saw it there appeared to *be* no question to extract. If there was one, it was unclear; if there wasn't, as I thought, then ... well, either unclear, or custom. And what is the freeform close/flag reason box for except unusual, non-predefined reasons?

Comment: I think the question was entirely contained in the title of the post.